# LINQ - "SQL statement is nested too deeply" issue in MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I am stuck for a while now, and was hoping someone can point me in the right directions.

below part of code throws me an error :
*"Some part of your SQL statement is nested too deeply. Rewrite the query or break it up into smaller queries"*

Can seomeone please advise me, how to write it in "smaller queries" ?

```
var cnpPendingForCogRole = (from p in db.udf_tbl_GetPendingCnpForRoleAboveStep4((int)CnpAbove4StepRolesEnum.CogManager, 0)
                                                join g in CogList on p.CogName equals g
                                                select p.cnpId).ToList();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Linq uses differed execution, try breaking apart the query so that it is not all trying to run at once.

```
 var query1 = db.udf_tbl_GetPendingCnpForRoleAboveStep4((int)CnpAbove4StepRolesEnum.CogManager, 0).ToList();
    var cnpPendingForCogRole = (from p in query1
                                join g in CogList on p.CogName equals g
                                                    select p.cnpId).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks, but still the same issue :/

Comment: is the statement i assiged to query1 a stored proceedure? What is  the actual SQL it references?

Comment: If the issue is actually delayed execution and it is trying to run the sql all at one time then i guess my previous answer wouldnt have fixed it. Try casting query1 to list then joining in the next query.

Comment: That was it. Thank you Rick !